# Why is the menu not showing on my Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using python 2.7.11 with Anaconda 2.4.1. I'm currently working through a Tkinter tutorial, found [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/menustoolbars/). I'm trying to display a simple menu on a GUI. The code I have been using is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Simple Menu")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu = menubar)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar)
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result of the code shows the following GUI.

[image]

I have tried similar codes from other websites that claim to render a GUI with a menu option, all of which render the same result. I have updated Anaconda and tried running from the XQuartz server with no avail. There are no error messages and all other Tkinter widgets seem to work fine (listboxes, text fields etc). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with Python 2.7.6, the menu appears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the look & feel of the GUI you posted, I assume you're on OS X. On OS X, the Menu is displayed separately, on the top menu bar. It is not displayed on the Window itself. Please check my screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, this is really not what I thought I was aiming for. Duh!!  Thanks alot!! :)

Comment: @JonSayer Please accept the answer if it's helpful :)

Comment: @JonSayer BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).  More than one answers. ;)

Comment: @MikeMüller We both have the same privilege too! ;-)

Comment: Just executed my privilege. :)

Comment: thank you guy, I faced the same issue and I've used more than one hour looking up the source of problème

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X the menu is at the top of the desktop. Not at the actual Tkinter window. Your code works.

Answer (score 1):

The command that does the job is root.configure(menu=ur_menu_bar). And this configuration should be done, post creating all your sub-menus and their corresponding commands. It must be given post at the end of your menu items.